# How to fix "zsh: command not found: vue"?

Tags: macos, npm, zsh, vue-cli

I installed @vue/cli on my mac, but whenever I type “vue”, my terminal says “zsh: command not found: vue” - How can I fix this problem? I searched similar issues and already spent half a day, but still not solved...

This is my environment:

- macOS Catalina version 10.15
- npm 6.4.1
- node v10.13.0

I changed $PATH by doing this:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Now this is:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

It looks like @vue/cli is installed, but I don't know why vue command is not found. Don't I have an admin privilege?

```
~ % npm install -g @vue/cli
/Users/ami/.npm_global/bin/vue -> /Users/ami/.npm_global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
+ @vue/cli@4.0.5
updated 1 package in 46.758s
~ % node -v
v10.13.0
~ % npm -v
6.4.1
~ % vue -v    
zsh: command not found: vue
~ % vue create new-project
zsh: command not found: vue
```

I'm following Vue CLI's instruction, so the result is supposed to be creating a new vue project.
https://cli.vuejs.org

---

***SOLVED***
Thank you for your advice!
I tried `~ % export PATH=~/.npm_global/bin:$PATH` and my path became:

```
~ % echo $PATH
/Users/ami/.npm_global/bin
:/usr/local/bin
:~/.npm_global/bin
:/usr/local/bin
:~/.npm_global/bin
:/usr/local/bin
:/usr/bin
:/bin
:/usr/sbin
:/sbin
:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
:/Library/Apple/bin
:/usr/local/share/dotnet
:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools
:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

And try again:

```
~ % vue --version
@vue/cli 4.0.5
```

Worked!

Comment: If `/usr/local/bin/vue` doesn't exist, then (re)adding `/usr/local/bin` to your path won't help. You need to add `~/.npm_global/bin` to your path.

Comment: For those who are struggling like I did: I have no `.npm_global` folder but instead there is `.npm-packages`. So this is what I had to execute: `export PATH=~/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @amithenl Since your problem is solved, can you please accept the answer, so the question doesn't stay open?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the first you should remove all vue cli by enter 2 command

```
npm uninstall --global vue-cli
npm uninstall --global @vue/cli
```

then you should enter this commad for install the latest version of vue cli

```
npm install --global @vue/cli@latest
```

I tried this in mac os 10.15.4 and worked

and then I install

```
@vue/cli 4.4.6
```

good luck :)

Comment: One should never use npm with sudo. change the export path as suggested by @alejandrodotor8

Comment: This solution worked for me in macOS M1 Monterrey

Answer (score 6):

You have to change the `.zhsrc` in `/Users/[username]/.zshrc` and add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[username]/.npm-global/bin
```

Check that your packages are in `npm-global` or `npm-packages`.

To see hidden file use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

if none of the above work

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

and

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

that's worked for me

Answer (score 2):

mac os catalina with zsh terminal

1. Uninstalled node and npm using https://www.positronx.io/how-to-uninstall-node-js-and-npm-from-macos/
2. Downloaded node/npm from https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
3. sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
4. vue --version (@vue/cli 4.5.4)

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above to no avail on Catalina 10.15.4

The fix is to

1. uninstall Node and Npm
2. go to [Downloads Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) and install the 64-bit version from [Package](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.2.0/node-v14.2.0.pkg)
3. `sudo npm install --global vue-cli`
4. `vue -V`

2.9.6

Comment: Worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Open **/etc/paths** file with *nano* or some other editor as a superuser (`sudo nano /etc/paths`).

Add following line at the bottom

`/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.2.1/bin`

Before that, just check the node version (mine is **15.2.1**).

Save changes, reboot your laptop and you're ready to go.